# Reorder boxplot in rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to reorder a boxplot based on the median.

```
mymonths <- c("Jan","Feb","Mar",
              "Apr","Mei","Jun",
              "Jul","Aug","Sep",
              "Okt","Nov","Dec")
df1 <- nycflights13::flights %>% 
  filter(dep_delay > 10) %>%
  select(month, arr_delay) %>% 
  filter(arr_delay < 480) %>%
  mutate(Maand  = mymonths[month])

ggplot(data = df1, mapping = aes(x = arr_delay, y = Maand)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = 'red', outlier.alpha = 0.1) +
  labs(x = "Vertraging bij aankomst", caption = "Vluchten die uit New York vertrekken") +
  ggtitle("Vertraging van vluchten per maand (in min)")
```

now i thought i could either use the function reorder() or fct_reorder(),
i would fill in something like `fct_reorder(Maand, arr_delay, fun = median)` into the aes() of x.
(tried switching "Maand"and "arr_delay" but it also doesn't work)
The boxplot without reorder looks perfect but once I use reorder it gives me something very weird.

any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried `fct_reorder(Maand, arr_delay, .fun = median)` and it looks good.

```
ggplot(data = df1, mapping = aes(x = arr_delay, y = fct_reorder(Maand, arr_delay, .fun = median))) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = 'red', outlier.alpha = 0.1) +
  labs(x = "Vertraging bij aankomst", caption = "Vluchten die uit New York vertrekken") +
  ggtitle("Vertraging van vluchten per maand (in min)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df1, mapping = aes(x = arr_delay, 
       y = forcats::fct_reorder(Maand, arr_delay))) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = 'red', outlier.alpha = 0.1) +
  labs(x = "Vertraging bij aankomst", 
       caption = "Vluchten die uit New York vertrekken") +
  ggtitle("Vertraging van vluchten per maand (in min)")
```

If you want the bars in opposite order use `y = forcats::fct_reorder(Maand, -arr_delay)`.

Comment: Just found an answer on my own! `ggplot(data = df1, mapping = aes(x = reorder(month, arr_delay, median), y = arr_delay)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = 'red', outlier.alpha = 0.1) +
  labs(y = "Vertraging bij aankomst", caption = "Vluchten die uit New York vertrekken") +
  ggtitle("Vertraging van vluchten per maand (in min)") +
  coord_flip()`